# Draggable flatlist not scrolling

Tags: android, css, react-native, draggable, react-native-flatlist

I have been working on a feature where a user drags and rearranges photos on a screen, but i find that when i run the app in my android phone, the container which contains the draggable "cards" does not scroll. But when I use emulator in my laptop, the screen scrolls easily.

im using DraggableFlatList from 'react-native-draggable-flatlist'

```
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
              <DraggableFlatList
                data={Object.keys(data)}
                vertical
                renderItem={({ item, index, drag, isActive }) => renderItem({ item, index, drag, isActive })}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item}
                onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
              />
            </ScrollView>
```

Comment: which package you are using?

Comment: im using DraggableFlatList from 'react-native-draggable-flatlist'

Comment: Can you use the inspector to ensure that there is no invisible view which obscure the draggable cards?